# Why this code giving run time exception when free-ing the pointer

Tags: c, runtime

I have simple code,

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <malloc.h>
int main()
{
  char *p = (char*) malloc(10);
  p = "Hello";

  free(p);

  return 0;
}
```

This code is giving run time exception while terminating. Below is error snippiest,

---

### Microsoft Visual C++ Debug Library

Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: ...\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\samC\Debug\samC.exe
File: f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\dbgheap.c
Line: 1322

Expression: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

### (Press Retry to debug the application)

### Abort   Retry   Ignore

Comment: Use `std::string` for the semantics you would expect of a string.

Comment: You are confusing p = "Hello" with strcpy(p, "hello)

Comment: It's a C code, so char * I need to use, secondly I was not getting cause of exception.

Comment: @PranitPKothari, If it's C, why is it tagged with C++?

Comment: @chris, Sorry, edited Tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you write a string in the memory allocated by malloc to a char pointer.

```
strcpy(p, "Hello");
```

Replace the line

```
p = "Hello";
```

with the `strcpy` one & your program will work fine.

You also need to

```
#include <string.h>
```

`malloc` returns a pointer to allocated memory. Say the address is 95000 (just a random number I pulled out).

So after the malloc - p will hold the address `95000`
The p containing `95000` is the memory address which needs to be passed to free when you are done with the memory.

However, the next line `p = "Hello";` puts the address of the string literal "Hello" (which say exists at address `25000`) into p.

So when you execute `free(p)` you are trying to free `25000` which wasn't not allocated by malloc.

OTOH, when you `strcpy`, you copy the string "Hello" into the address starting at p (i.e. `95000`). `p` remains `95000` after the strcpy.

And `free(p)` frees the right memory.

You can also avoid the `malloc` and use

```
char *p = "Hello";
```

However, in this method, you cannot modify the string.

i.e. if after this you do `*p = 'B'` to change the string to `Bello`, it becomes an undefined operation. This is not the case in the `malloc` way.

If instead, you use

```
char p[] = "Hello";
```

or

```
char p[10] = "Hello";
```

you get a modifiable string which need not be `free`d.

Answer (score 6):

`p = "Hello";` makes `p` point to a string literal and discards the previously assigned value. You can't `free` a string literal. You can't modify it.

If you want `p` to hold that string, just use

```
char* p = "Hello";
```

or

```
char p[] = "Hello";
```

if you plan on modifying it.

Neither requires `free`.

Comment: So what will happen to memory allocated with malloc?

Comment: @PranitPKothari it will leak.

Answer (score 2):

```
p = "Hello";
free(p);
```

Since `Hello` is statically allocated, you cannot `free` it. I'm not sure why you allocate some memory just to throw the pointer away by changing it to another pointer, but that has no effect. If you do this:

```
int i = 1;
i = 2;
```

`i` has no memory that it once held a `1`, it holds a `2` now. Similarly, `p` has no memory that it once held a pointer to some memory you allocated. It holds a pointer to an immutable constant now.

Answer (score 1):

this is a nice one.
the char sequence "hello" is constant and therefore placed niether on the heap nor the stack, but in the .bss/.data segment. when you do `p="hello"` you make p point to the address of the string hello in that segment instead of the memory you alocated on the heap using `malloc`. when you go to `free` p it tries to free the memory in the .bss/.data segment, and naturally fails.

what you probably want is something like `strcpy(p,"hello");` which goes over every char in "hello" and places it in the memory pointed to by p. essentially creating a copy of the string "hello" at memory address p.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the contents of the string "Hello" to the memory you allocated, you need to use `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(p, "Hello");
```

The line

```
p = "Hello";
```

assigns the *address* of the string literal "Hello" to the pointer `p`, overwriting the pointer value that was returned from `malloc`, hence the crash when you call `free`.